# JQuery Accordion not working, Item showing but will not animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Exactly as the title suggests. Basically, I downloaded a nice accordion template from the web, but when i add it into my website, it doesn't work. I'v followed their documentation, and managed to get it working in a separate, empty html document, but no luck in my own website.

Here's my code, sorry about how awful it is, I'm new to this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/index.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<style type="text/css">
@import url("SILXCSS.css");
</style>
<title>Silx</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
// ]]>
</script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/evoslider.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default/default.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.evoslider.lite-1.1.0.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    }

img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }

img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
</style>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->

<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>



<body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo">
            <h1> 
                … 
            </h1>
      <div class="fadehover">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="" class="a" /></a>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.gif" alt="" class="b" /></a>

      </div>
</div>      
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
                <ul id="menu">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="partners.html">Partners</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://silx.boards.net/">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="page" class="container">
      <div id="content">
        <div id="onecolumn"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->
            <div id="mySlider" class="evoslider default">    
                <dl>

                    <dt>slide one</dt>
                    <dd data-src="image1.jpg" data-thumb="image1-thumb.jpg">
                    </dd>

                    <dt>slide two</dt>
                    <dd data-src="image2.jpg" data-thumb="image2-thumb.jpg">
                    </dd>

                    <dt>slide three</dt>
                    <dd data-src="image3.jpg" data-thumb="image3-thumb.jpg">
                    </dd>

                    <dt>slide four</dt>
                    <dd data-src="image4.jpg" data-thumb="image4-thumb.jpg">
                    </dd>  

                </dl>
            </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var myEvoSlider = $("#mySlider").evoSlider();
        </script> 
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
        </div>
    </div>



<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.a").hover(
    function() 
    {       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");                           },
    function() 
    {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
    });

});

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu > li:has(ul)").mouseenter(function(){
          $(this).children("ul").css("display", "none");
          $(this).children("ul").css("left", "auto").fadeIn('slow');
        }).mouseleave(function(){
          $(this).children("ul").delay(300).fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).children("ul").css("left", "-9999em");
          });
        });
      });

$("ul#menu > li").fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
$("ul#menu > li").hover(
    function() { $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); },
    function() { $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5); }
);




function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>      
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: jsFiddles are perfect for things like these

Comment: There might be some JQuery/JavaScript conflicts on your webpage.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Anything more specific you guys can point out? I'm at a loss, I'v moved some of the code around to see if that helps with not much luck!

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> I think these two scripts are conflicting each other, try removing 1.10.1.min and then try else look for adding No Conflict  for the javascripts. I'm not sure but this might work. Also check the code of both the CSS files, some attributes might be conflicting.

Comment: Thanks, will try this tomorrow and post back. Really appreciate this guys, this website is for a good cause and your feedback is greatly welcomed!

Comment: Rahul Dwivedi thank you so much, deleting the 1.10.1.min fixed it! All working well now, thank you to everybody who answered, your time is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JoeSteel You are welcome.I've posted this as an answer now. If you feel you can accept that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>
```

**and**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`
```

are conflicting with each other, try after removing `1.10.1.min.js`.